# Why does my header (a grid) change its layout when position:fixed is applied?

Tags: css, header, css-grid

I have a header that works as expected until I apply position:fixed;

I'm practicing with grids to complete a beginner level freecodecamp project. The header is a grid with two items side by side, where one gets pushed to a new row at a specified width. That's all as intended, and I understand the overall responsiveness is far from ideal, but it's sufficient given my knowledge level.

**The problem:** a requirement is to have it fixed to the top. But when I apply position:fixed; to the grid (it's line 7, though in practice line 7 and 8 go together), it pushes the second grid item to a new row despite the width not changing.

Any idea what's going on here?

Other weird things are happening, like the grid outline scrolls off the page despite the elements remaining fixed to the top, but I don't know if that's necessarily part of the main question here.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(500px, 1fr));
    position: fixed; /* HERE */
    top: 0; /* AND HERE */
    }

    #header-img {
    grid-area: image;
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    }

    #nav-ul {
    grid-area: nav;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    }

    #nav-ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div>
        <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul id="nav-ul">
            <a href=""><li class="nav-link">Features</li></a>
            <a href=""><li class="nav-link">How It Works</li></a>
            <a href=""><li class="nav-link">Pricing</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set a width on the header

Comment: Isn't that what minmax() in line 6 does? grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(500px, 1fr));

Comment: Also, thank you for your response. I guess ultimately the question is aimed at helping me understand CSS Grid. So in particular, I'm trying to figure out what's happening (why is this happening)? Why does the grid layout change just because position:fixed; is applied?

Comment: Nope a fixed element collapses to its minimum width

Comment: Bingo! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the header CSS property.See the snippet.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(500px, 1fr));
    position: fixed; /* HERE */
     /* AND HERE */
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #header-img {
    grid-area: image;
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    }

    #nav-ul {
    grid-area: nav;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    }

    #nav-ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div>
        <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul id="nav-ul">
            <a href=""><li class="nav-link">Features</li></a>
            <a href=""><li class="nav-link">How It Works</li></a>
            <a href=""><li class="nav-link">Pricing</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```